# Editing questions

Tags: support, edits

Something weird happened to me. On the main site (Stack Overflow) I have an account with low reputation points (196) and until two days ago I was able to edit others people questions.
So till then I believed that editing questions is allowed no-matter how low is your reputation points.

Suddenly (two days ago) I realized that I couldn't edit questions anymore. "Account is not allowed to suggest edits", is the message appearing when I hover over the edit link now. By searching the site information I saw that editing requries at least 2,000 reputation points.

How was I able to edit the question in the first days?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first, you could suggest edits. You can do this at any amount of rep. Your edits must go through a queue to be reviewed though. (At 2000 reputation, you don't have to go through a queue and your edits edit automatically.)

What probably happened is that too many of your edits were rejected, so you can't suggest edits anymore.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1757120) are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1757255) of [your](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1757236) edits [that](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1755490) were rejected as "too minor." All you did was add a tag (and in the message you said "improved formatting" which doesn't make much sense.) Please only make substantive edits that improved multiple parts of the post.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1755602) are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1754278) more "Too minor" edits.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1755456) edit, you added "Thank you." Please don't do that, it is clutter and frowned upon at Stack Overflow.

I can see this in your stats:

> Editor Stats
>
> - apomene had 65 edit suggestions approved, and 27 edit suggestions rejected

Comment: Although it is a "taboo"- "Thank you a Lot".. a really appreciate for the feedback..

Comment: @apomene: not in questions. It makes it look like you're soliciting answers. Thank me _after_ I give the answer, if you really really want, as a comment.

Comment: Or more appropriately by assigning the checkmark below the answer if you asked it :D

Comment: How long before edit rights be restored?@Doorknob

Comment: @kabuto178 The ban is 1 week long

Comment: To regain permission to edit, will it be done automatically?

Comment: @kabuto178 yes.