# Suggested edit. Only one tag added or removed

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Is there any rule or discussion where I can read the information - how to review the suggested edit with only one tag added or removed?

For example some question that has already `C#` tag, become also `C# 4.0` one.

Is it minor one?

Sure I dont mean the situation where the `C#` code question has not `C#` tag at all.

One more example - question has `Entity Framework 4.0` tag and become also `Entity Framework`.
Minor?

Comment: Same guidelines as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/152859). In short: reject.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173141/213634

Comment: @AndersUP - I have seen your link - its not completely my question

Comment: If you have researched by reading other questions on the subject, please include that information in your question. What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191842/213634)?

Comment: Or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170392/213634) when the tag edit is actually substantial.

Comment: If they're adding a more general tag (C# where there was only C# 4), I'd say approve. If they're adding a more specific tag (C# 4 where there was only C#), only approve if the question is about functionality / a bug / something unique to that version. I wanted to include "from that version onwards", but 10 years from now, all versions will have that functionality.

Comment: @AndersUP No, at 16k questions and 2.4k followers, I wouldn't say [tag:c#-4.0] is a minor tag.

Comment: @Dukeling - you see here are the users with more than 10k points on SO and no straight line how to handle such an edits not to become ban for it )

Comment: @Dukeling Well, in [one of the suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/240464#./240464?&_suid=138070832685209709592859284879) examplified in what I flagged this to be a dupe of, a Winform tag with 2.2k followers and 41k questions is rejected. Are you saying that the 200 diff in followers constitute the difference into making C#4-0 more major than [Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms)? I think the discussion is exactly the same.

Comment: @Dukeling I personally believe that retagging (properly) is important, but I respect the apparent consensus that it shouldn't be done by <2Ks that have to have their edits approved. At any rate I'm just trying to bring relevant, similar questions into this so we don't just restart from square one again.

Comment: @AndersUP I don't know enough about the topic, but if [tag:winforms] was really appropriate for that question I believe it should've been approved - it's not a particularly minor tag and it looks distinct enough from any tags already present (unlike C# vs C# 4, since C# 4 is a subset of C#).

Comment: @Dukeling Exactly. So the potential dupe may have a wrong title, in that they weren't all minor, but the discussion is essentially the same. That said, I agree with your comment on when to approve above.