# Editing question titles

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I proposed [three small edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774/cbowns?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on Stack Overflow yesterday (all around correcting the capitalization of a framework title on iOS). I didn't know until I read about it [just now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173140/editing-questions/173141#173141) that if your edits are rejected, you lose the ability to propose edits on questions and answers for a week.

Two points here: (and apologies if I'm doing meta. wrong, this is the first time anything like this has come up.)

1. I'm terribly sorry, I was just trying to clean up the CoreBluetooth part of the world. I didn't know there was a timeout on this. Can I get my edit suggestion privileges restored?
2. I don't agree with a policy that discourages making small corrections to question titles on the site: they're a leading signal of question quality. If I saw a question title like "core BlueTooth: …", my brain assumes "this author is an idiot" and I don't bother reading the question.

Comment: can you link to the edits please? I can't find them from your profile

Comment: @KateGregory http://stackoverflow.com/users/774/cbowns?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Linked in the post.

Comment: @cbowns You have more than three recent rejected edits, those are just what put you over the edge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those posts have lots of other things to be fixed. This isn't a surprise: when someone cannot even correctly spell the technology they're having a problem using, they generally misspell other words too.

Since your edits have to be reviewed, fix everything that needs to be fixed. Use the easily-searchable spelling mistake as a way to find the posts, but don't only fix that one mistake. Look for:

- other spelling errors
- grammar errors
- code and keywords inline that needs backticks ` around it
- large blocks of code that need to be indented 4 spaces to look like code
- check the tags - some use too many, others too few
- break up a wall of text into something readable
- if they've linked elsewhere for a picture, and you have enough rep to bring it inline, do so

Now you're really contributing! (Or at least, you will be a week from now.)

Comment: Agreed, and that all makes sense. (I want to state one thing, though: right now, I'm more than a bit frustrated that it's a full week and not a day or two.)

Comment: I would be too. All I can say is that if you had been monitoring your suggestions and searched here on "too minor" you could have changed your ways before the suggestion-suspension kicked in. Cold comfort, though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sure.  All you have to do is wait a week.  Use that time to learn a bit more about what kind of edits are allowed, read around a bit on some related meta posts to see what type of edits we do/don't like.  Pay attention to the edits you see made on posts you're looking at.  (And pay attention to which are suggested edits and which are from 2k users.)
2. Then see one of the *many* past discussions on the topic.  Read through the various arguments for and against rejecting very minor edits.  Either post a new answer to one of the existing discussions, or if you must bring the discussion up again, be prepared to explain why the arguments previously brought up against allowing minor edits don't apply or can be addressed, and ensure that the points that you are bringing up in favor of the change have not already been brought up and discussed in the past.

   That, or you could just not make minor edits and instead fix up the rest of the post when editing those titles.   (Or both, you can do both.)

Comment: I suppose you're right. Looking back at older edits that I thought were both substantive and improved Stack Overflow's quality, some have garnered reject votes or been outright rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3108902 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2621617